# Passing Non-Item Values to Properties in ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

Today I'm having trouble passing values from a parent control down to the properties of a child control in a list.

I have a custom control which I've made which functions as a Thumbnail Check Box. Essentially it's just a checkbox wrapped around an image with some nice borders. It's all wrapped up into a DLL and deployed as a custom control

If I want to use a single instance of the control, I can do so like this...

```
<tcb:ThumbnailCheckBox IsChecked="True"
                       ImagePath="D:\Pictures\123.jpg"
                       CornerRadius="10"
                       Height="{Binding ThumbnailSize}"
                       Margin="10" />
```

**Code Listing 1 - Single Use**

This works great, and easily binds to ThumbnailSize on my ViewModel so I can change the size of the image in the control however I want.

The problem is when I want to expand the use of this control into a list, I'm running into a few problems.

To begin, I've styled the ListBox control to meet my needs like so...

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}"
       x:Key="WrappingImageListBox">
    <!-- Set the ItemTemplate of the ListBox to a DataTemplate 
       which explains how to display an object of type BitmapImage. -->
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <tcb:ThumbnailCheckBox ImagePath="{Binding ImagePath}"
                                       IsChecked="{Binding Selected}"
                                       Height="{TemplateBinding utilities:MyAttachedProperties.ImageSize}"
                                       CornerRadius="8"
                                       Margin="10">
                </tcb:ThumbnailCheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!-- Swap out the default items panel with a WrapPanel so that
       the images will be arranged with a different layout. -->
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <!-- Set this attached property to 'Disabled' so that the 
       ScrollViewer in the ListBox will never show a horizontal 
       scrollbar, and the WrapPanel it contains will be constrained 
       to the width of the ScrollViewer's viewable surface. -->
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
            Value="Disabled" />
</Style>
```

**Code Listing 2 - ListBox Style**

And I call it like this from my main view...

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DirectoryPictures}"
         Grid.Row="1"
         Style="{DynamicResource WrappingImageListBox}"
         Background="Transparent" 
         util:MyAttachedProperties.ImageSize="500"/>
```

**Code Listing 3 - Main Call**

This works exactly as I'd like, except for the `ImageSize` property. Both `ImagePath` and `Selected` are properties of the individual list items being bound to the `ListBox`.

As you can see, I created an attached property to try to pass the value (`500`), but it doesn't seem to be working. I should note that I think the style I've created is correct because the elements use the default value.

```
public static class MyAttachedProperties
{
    public static double GetImageSize(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(ImageSizeProperty);
    }

    public static void SetImageSize(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageSizeProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ImageSize",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(MyAttachedProperties),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(50D));
}
```

**Code Listing 4 - Attached Property**

The `50D` specified on the last line is applying to the listed control. If I change it, and recompile, the end result changes. But the sent value of `500` I specified in my `ListBox` Main call (listing 3) is not ever sent. Of course, I would eventually like to change the `500` into a bound property on my view model, but I won't do that until I get it working with an explicit value.

Can someone help me figure out how to send a value from my main `ListBox` call (listing 3) and apply it to the individual items that are populated by the template? The other properties I have work, but they are a properties of each item in the List I'm binding to the `ListBox`, whereas `ImageSize` is not.

---

***EDIT To address First Response***

This seems to be working, but it's kind of peculiar. My listbox is now being called like so...

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DirectoryPictures}"
         Grid.Row="1"
         Style="{DynamicResource WrappingImageListBox}"
         Background="Transparent" />
```

And I've changed my style to the code you suggested...

```
<tcb:ThumbnailCheckBox ImagePath="{Binding ImagePath}"
                       IsChecked="{Binding Selected}"
                       Height="{Binding Path=DataContext.ThumbnailSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                       CornerRadius="8"
                       Margin="10">
```

My only concern is, now the style is accessing the ViewModel for that control directly rather than receiving a bound value.

Suppose I wanted to use the `ListBox` again, but on another `UserControl` whose `ViewModel` didn't have `ThumbnailSize` property, but used one by another name?

You see where I'm going with this... the current solution is not very extensible and is limited to the current classes as they are named exactly.

In fact, in a perfect world, I'd like to have variable names for the `ImagePath` and `Selected` properties, but that's a different discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use `FindAncestor`. The idea of that is, child traverses through logical tree, and tries to find parent with concrete type (in this case, `ListBox`), and then accesses attached property. See http://wpftutorial.net/BindingExpressions.html for more binding expressions.

In your `ItemTemplate`, this is how you could access `ThumbnailSize` property:

```
{Binding Path=(util:MyAttachedProperties.ImageSize), 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                           Mode=FindAncestor,
                           AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}
```

Essentially, the question asked here was a little bit opposite, but results are same. "How could items in `ListBox` access `ListBox` (attached) properties.

Comment: Made an edit to the original post to ask some questions about this solution. Thanks!

Comment: @imdandman; yes, what you're saying makes sense. You can bind against the attached property (updated the post). You should probably create a new `UserControl` and wrap the `ListBox` in it, and expose `ThumbnailSize` property. The attached property seems fishy.

Comment: This did it! Thank you! I'm going to replicate it for the corner radius and margin properties. Quick question though - is there a "cleaner" way to do it rather than using the attached properties? Making attached properties for all of them is kind of messy, but it works and is a lot more straightforward than any other halfway solution I've seen out there. Thanks again! This is awesome.

Comment: @imdanman: Yes, attached properties are not necessarily recommended here. You should create new `UserControl`, and add dependency properties there(no attached). Create new control, call it `YourImageGallery` or whatever.